# React - Import multiple images in given directory

Tags: reactjs, function, webpack, lambda, export

```
const importAll = require =>
  require.keys().reduce((acc, next) => {
    acc[next.replace("./", "")] = require(next);
    return acc;
  }, {});

const images = importAll(
  require.context('./images', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);

console.log(images);
```

I have the above block of code that imports all files in a given directory given that they end in the required type however, I want to reuse this code so that I can import it into different modules across my app and specify the path for each individual module.

I've also tried the below block of code but am new to this syntax, any help is appreciated!

```
const importAll = require =>
  require.keys().reduce((acc, next) => {
    acc[next.replace("./", "")] = require(next);
    return acc;
  }, {});

const images = (path) => importAll(
  require.context(path, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);

export default {
    images,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that It's because require.context will only take a literal regex in webpack 4 and therefore, not a variable.

See here https://webpack.docschina.org/guides/dependency-management/

However, mcm-ham found a work around which can be viewed here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4772?fbclid=IwAR3m6kmghtm4EoV8IspcqEfFItdeMnzQHGiEkXbwqgOywXSUFxcWXxbyjRI#issuecomment-344556837